# I can't open SQL Server 2014 "Cannot connect to server"

Tags: sql, sql-server

After setup I can't open my SQL Server Management Studio:

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to 0.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)
>
> The network path was not found

Comment: Did you actually install SQL Server also or only Management Studio?

Comment: i installed both of them

Comment: *The network path was not found* seems to be pretty clear. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18060667/62576) has a lot of troubeshooting suggestions that will probably help you resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case what it worked for me was the Hosts file in the folder C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

I was trying to connect into a SQL server with a name that has an entry in the HOSTS file; however, the IP in the HOSTS file was unreachable - Nonexisting -

First, I connected using my SQL  client using the IP address and it was no problem.
Next, I delete the entry for the SQL server name in the HOST file in the folder C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc, saved it and again tried to connect into that SQL server using the name that I just deleted from the host file and it went thru without issues.

I hope it helps someone along the way

Answer (score 0):

It happened for me, but it is nor serious problem. If database is in your local, may be u must boot IIS or SQLEXPRESS manually in Services of Windows.
And may be, you are writing incorrect name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. In Windows, go to Services >> SQL Server related to your instance >> Right Click >> Start
2. Again in Services >> SQL Server AGENT related to your instance >> Right Click >> Start

Try connecting the instance again using SSMS.

Regards,

Pratik

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying `Cannot connect to 0.` That `0` is where it would normally give the name of the instance it was trying to connect to. Which implies that you gave it `0` as the name of the SQL instance to connect to, which is never going to work.

You need to give it the name of the machine where the SQL server service has been installed (or use shortcuts like `.` or `localhost` to represent the current machine) and if the instance name was not the default instance name, you need to follow the machine name with backslash and the instance name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to the local instance via SQL Server Management. You can expand the server name box and click the . Then you can browse the local servers via expand the "Database Engine". Please click the instance name which you want to connect so that you can avoid fat figures.

[Browse for Servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjhqP.png)

Besides, if you want to connect to the default instance on the local computer, please specify the server name as "localhost" or " . ". For detailed information, please refer to the document.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/logging-in-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017